# why "models.py" is not required in django when using mongodb as backend?

Tags: python, django, mongodb

Recetly I've seen an app powered with django and mongodb as backend,thing is that app doesn't have a models.py file.All the datas are inserted directly in views.py.I Just need a little clarification about this particular things "Using django without models.py with mongodb."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

models.py is the Django ORM way of inspecting a fixed relational schema and generating the relevant SQL code to initialize (or modify) the database. "ORM" stands for "Object-Relational Mapping".

Mongo is not relational, hence you don't need this type of schema.

(Of course, that can cause a lot of other problems if the needs of your project change later...)

But you don't need a relational schema since you're not using a relational DB.

Comment: it is of coarse never "required" even if using an sql backend (It tends to be a good idea though)

Comment: @JoranBeasley It is required if you want the database backend to be generated by the ORM instead of hand-mapping everything. But for folks not using the ORM, sure, its not absolutely necessary. (Sadly, I know far too much about [using non-ORM models in Django](http://zxq9.com/archives/616)...)

Answer (score 2):

**A short answer**

models.py is the ORM that comes free with django.
ORM relates your SQL schema into oopsy objects.
You can read more about ORM here-> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping.

When using a noSQL, you can push objects directly into DB. So, you do not really need an ORM.

That said, whether to use it or not is a debatable part.

PS. even while using SQL, some people prefer other ORMs instead of django's built-in models.